# To all my friends here: My farewell

Tags: discussion

To all friends here on SuperUser.

It has become clear that the devs are not going to make any changes to the visuals with ignored tags, which makes it just too hard for me to keep things clear.

See here for details: [My brain cannot ignore the ignored questions due to contrast change. Please change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382047/my-brain-cannot-ignore-the-ignored-questions-due-to-contrast-change-please-chan/384124#384124)

From this point on, I'll not be active anymore on SuperUser. I'll keep my answers on the site, and I've written many quality answers, but if the devs don't listen to their users to keep this a great place, then I don't want to be in it anymore.

Comment: It's always sad to see a long time user go so rather than goodbye let's just say "au revoir" until we meet again.

Comment: Thank you @Mokubai I really don't want to go, but its just not working for me anymore, and if the devs don't even care to give me any reaction, then I just know the time has come for me to leave. It'll create a void in my daily live, and I don't know yet how I will replace that with anything, but the devs just don't give me any choice.

Comment: I've appreciated your contributions over the years. best wishes.

Comment: Thank you @FrankThomas. The feeling is mutual.

Comment: To my good friend LPChip.  Please take a rest and then come back slowly.  We would all appreciate you being here, I am sure.

Comment: Thank you @John. Maybe I'll come back one day. And if the developers realize how big of a userbase this change is affecting and they fix it soon, it will not have to take that long either.

Comment: I don't use/subscribe(?) to any tag so can't comment. But I have one question: does the contrast also worst in dark mode? I don't think we have communicated with each other a lot, but the site will miss your knowledge. There were many questions I could not understand what OPs were asking, and you were the one explaining the clearly the issue. See you soon back here. The site needs more people like you!

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio thank you. That means a lot to me. Yes, the problem is much worse in dark mode.

Comment: Thank you for all your excellent answers over the years.  You will be missed.  Sorry the UI/UX of SE/SU/SO isn't acceptable for you.  I find it lacking too, so I wrote a custom style to improve the UI/UX for SE/SU/SO.  I recall reading that SE made the determination that it was too challenging to make a quality dark theme for all the SE sites.  I did find it time consuming, but not too challenging.  The resultant UI does resolve the issue that is causing you to leave after all these years of being a prolific contributor.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket thank you. :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you could try this extension for Chrome (or a similar for Firefox) to change the CSS styles of the ignored tags for yourself:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha

https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/

Answer (score 2):

First words - I would ask you to stay on our site, as I see you as
one of the more knowledgeable voices here. I found many of your
answers and your comments to be interesting and educative.

Second, SuperUser/StackOverflow has made more than one unfortunate
design decision for the user interface, and user protests are not
always taken in account.

However, rather than leaving the site in protest, you could fix
the problem yourself by modifying the interface to suite you.
The tools you can use are the browser extensions of
GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey, which someone like you should have
no problem in writing the userscript to change these tag colors.
(Or you could post a question about it...)

For example, I have found the latest UI changes to be
counter-productive, so I use now the GreaseMonkey userscript
[SpectricSO / stack-scripts](https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts)
that made the Questions screen more compact and readable (for me).

Comment: Thank you for your kind words. The problem is that I'm forced to use Chrome at work with GPO active that dictates what extensions are used. I can't get around it. My boss also mentioned that its not allowed, so I really can't get around it.

Comment: Could you use a virtual machine, as it's isolated from the host computer?

Comment: I may be able to get around it. Problem is, its company policy, so there is no way for me to make it work other than StackExchange natively supporting it, or risk losing my job.

Comment: On MediaWiki, users can write their own userscript and CSS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:User_style & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:User_scripts It might be a good idea to implement that here.

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні: You are commenting on my answer - please delete your comment and paste it below the post itself, so as to address the poster and not me.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know you, but I thought I'd take a stab at tackling your need. I mean no harm, and if I my attempt to help is not useful, please forgive me. I will not take it personally if you downvote to indicate that it is not helpful :)

(To give other readers context,) In [one of your comments](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14840/to-all-my-friends-here-my-farewell?cb=1#comment43488_14843), you say:

> Thank you for your kind words. The problem is that I'm forced to use Chrome at work with GPO active that dictates what extensions are used. I can't get around it. My boss also mentioned that its not allowed, so I really can't get around it.

[And then](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/14840#comment43490_14843):

> I may be able to get around it. Problem is, its company policy, so there is no way for me to make it work other than StackExchange natively supporting it, or risk losing my job.

I have never heard of GPO, but I'm guessing it is [Windows' Group Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy) thing (which I've also never heard of. I'm not exactly inspiring confidence here, am I)?

On Chrome v65+, there is a feature called [Local Overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides), which lets you make modified versions of files served from the network (stored in your local filesystem), and tell Chrome to use your modified version instead of the network one. This will not make for a very maintainable solution, since it may/will need updating whenever the official site CSS changes, but I think it may be at least workable for you.

There are a number of ways you could possibly go about leveraging this.

Probably the easiest is to edit the https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/stacks.css?v=5e163053a5b0 file (or whatever `v=####` it is (yes this will be annoying)) and add:

```css
.s-post-summary__ignored {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Other options [for fun and <strike>profit</strike>](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/25205/468411) shenanigans:

```css
/* quick and dirty. only changes text- doesn't change tags appearance */
.s-post-summary__ignored {
    --black-500: var(--black-100);
}
```

Maybe there's a different stylesheet file that's more stable where this CSS rule could be added, but I don't know personally know about that detail.

Comment: Huh. TIL I cannot start an answer post with "Hello stranger!".

Comment: I didn't read through your MSE post before writing this, so I only now noticed that [this answer suggesting the opacity style](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/382051/997587) had already been made. So I guess the only info I am contributing is the existence of the "Local Overrides" feature.

Comment: +1. I have to see if I can get this to work. Its currently busy at work, so I have to find time for it and see if I can get it to work. Thanks for the suggestion though.